# Marvell 88SE9128 (9123?) SATA Card Weird Behaviour - OpenSUSE

Tags: opensuse, sata

after no response on the OpenSUSE forum (here: https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/511116-Sata-card-erratic-behaviour-amp-failure-Marvell-88SE9128-(9123-)-Chipset ) I am posing this query to Unix Stackexchange in the hope of wider reach.

So:

I have a Dell T20 running as a Home Server on OpenSUSE 64Bit - 1 500GB drive for the OS and 4 3TB harddrives with RAID6 for storage. As the Dell only has 4 on board SATA ports, it had to be expanded - in my case with a StarTech (PEXSAT32) 2x SATA3 card using a Marvell 88SE9128 chipset. (Weirdly OpenSUSE reports it as 88SE9123)

The issue I face is that the card behaves erratically, dropping a drive from the array... (though it has added it correctly in the past, it has been an on and off issue for a good year...)
Tech support suggested testing it outside of the array - zero filling the drive results in a failure at different times, anything from 1.5GB to 10+GB - but the drive gets dropped, this is true for the original 3TB drive as well as a 2TB drive. (Both drives are fine.) The zero fill will start at around 54MB/s and then starts to drop, often dying at 10-20MB/s, but I have seen it as low as 500KB/s.
Another suggestion was to try another computer - my desktop unfortunately only runs Windows, but testing the 2 and 3TB drive with 8/16GB CrystalDiskMark in a sequential write gave me no failure and resulted in around 190MB/s read speed and 150MB/s write speed, as expected for those harddrives (and the speed the array gets during rebuilds on the internal Intel SATA ports).

Unfortunately tech support could not offer any further suggestions, however the Windows test suggests the card itself is fine.
Swapping PCI slots on the Dell made no difference either.
While I have tested swapping the SATA cable, the same cable worked fine on my desktop, so I doubt it is the problem.

It is my understanding that the card should just work - as the controller is supported by Linux and should hence just work, unfortunately it does not.
Any ideas, any suggestions? How can this be investigated further? (This is where a forum would be better I guess...)

I am aware that many consider Marvell chips to be evil, but unfortunately I cannot afford a several hundred Pounds RAID card (nor do I really need it as I am using software RAID).
Another SATA card that I have with a 3123 SiI chip is not recognised by either the Dell or my desktop... (could be a compatibility issue or dead card...)

Updates following the suggestions from chanik: (25th Nov 2015)

I used the recommended command, `echo 1 > /sys/block/sde/device/queue_depth` to set the queue depth to one, using `cat /sys/block/sde/device/queue_depth` I verified that it was set to 1 (whether the setting was respected is another question).

In either case, using dd to zero the drive or actually a partition on the drive fails.
Following some further comments I reran the test - just in case something funny happens with the controller with dd, I created a fresh GPT table on the drive with a brand new ext4 partition spanning the entire drive and then copied a large directory to the drive. (Failed in both cases, but weirdly enough lived for 48GB with NCQ and 180GB without NCQ this time...)

For troubleshooting I copied/collected the output in /var/log/messages after the error occured and for NCQ set to 1, I also dumped the dmesg output to a logfile after the error occured.

(Text hsoted on Pastebin)

- Default NCQ: http://pastebin.com/RKBm2n7E
- NCQ Set to 1: http://pastebin.com/E9bciMs8
- dmesg output: http://pastebin.com/tN9wFMMb

-> if I read the dmesg log correctly, this may suggest that NCQ=1 was not respected

dmesg after reboot and after manually setting ncq to 1, looks like it is truly not respected...

- After Reboot: http://pastebin.com/TAUGACq7
- Setting NCQ: http://pastebin.com/GvAibnUW

Edit 2 - 25th Nov 2015:

Decided to use libata.force=noncq via Kernel parameters - still failed... 
dmesg output at http://pastebin.com/EQt5z5F3

Edit 26th Nov 2015:

With some suggestions to try an older Kernel as well as Windows I tested a fresh install as well as updated OpenSUSE 13.2 as well as a fresh install of Windows 7 (this one 32Bit, Linux is 64Bit) with the Marvell driver.

Under Linux copies or writes failed - be it to the drive itself or to the NTFS partition from Windows, under Windows the drive benchmarked fine.

OpenSUSE 13.2 fresh: http://pastebin.com/ucmiVqKL
OpenSUSE 13.2 updated: http://pastebin.com/uA1e1rc2
OpenSUSE 13.2 updated no NCQ: http://pastebin.com/QFLeUC8r

Copy to Windows NTFS partition under Leap 42.1 Kernel 4.1: http://pastebin.com/4iZtkBjZ

Windows 7 CrystalDiskMark benchmarks: http://pastebin.com/FJASyDpt

I also cannot understand why the chip is seen as a 9123, both in Windows as well as Linux - the chip clearly says 9128:

[image: Photo of the Marvell Chip clearly stating 9128]

Edit 2 - 26th Nov 2015
Ran Ubuntu from a USB drive with Kernel 3.13 (with ncq) - failed again

- dmesg: http://pastebin.com/pSeeAbNm
- lshw: http://pastebin.com/tP6c874P

Edit 27th Nov 2015

Ubuntu LiveUSB with Kernel 13.3 again - setting ncq via the command line, failed again.

- before setting ncq: http://pastebin.com/ivZmuPXc
- after setting ncq: http://pastebin.com/7Q4rUZUJ
- after failed zeroing of drive: http://pastebin.com/j9MHhKYV

Update 2nd Dec 2015

Little add on notes - got a new card with an Asmedia chip which works well.

Before I switched in the new card I did some more tests with an older harddrive I had lying around which I may add to my server for non-RAID duty.
The old drive is a SATA2, 2.5" harddrive with an advertised 120GB, well, no change... - also searched around a bit and disabled the write cache... still failed...

As usual I collected dmesg output, one while it was running prior to failure in case someone is interested and otherwise after failure.
As usual, files hosted by Pastebin.

- Just running dd with defaults: http://pastebin.com/PkF5W7zr
- dd while it was running: http://pastebin.com/eAgu7gXj
- dd with noncq set manually via command line: http://pastebin.com/FKhFMMd8
- dd with noncq set manuall and no write cache via hdparm: http://pastebin.com/icEgbKN4

And if I switch the BIOS to support legacy mode on my Dell T20, I can enter the card's menu too - photo below.
The only option it actively gives you, is to create a RAID 0/1 array in there or leave it as it is.

[image: PEXSAT32 BIOS options/screen]

Edit May 2017:
This problem was never truly resolved and the Kernel mailing list didn't provide any real answers either. As a result, the SATA card was changed to a different model and everything seemed to work. Fast forward, throughout 2016, two drives failed - and apparently both are truly dead.
All drives in my home server were switched and during the process I discovered that at least one of the SATA cables was faulty - in this case the OS drive cable. I also replaced the SATA cable for the card and things seem to work. This makes me wonder whether all the problems were due to a faulty cable and worse error correction under Linux... maybe? I won't know as I don't really have a good way of testing whether this would resolve the issue.

However, as a maybe: If irrational behaviour occurs, maybe try buying new cables, maybe that will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have Asus P7P55D-E EVO board with 88SE9123 onboard controller and experienced erratic behaviour on the HDDs attached to this controller.

Simple workaround is disabling the NCQ on the ports of 88SE9123
by adding something like following line on `/etc/default/grub` file.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="libata.force=7.00:noncq,8.00:noncq"
```

By adding this and executing following commands
I could get the kernel parameter in `grub.conf` modified in Ubuntu Linux.

```
$ sudo update-grub
$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

I've no experience on OpenSuse so you have to figure out how to change the
kernel parameter for boot time in your distro.

As an immediate cure, you can disable the NCQ of specific HDDs as follows.

```
$ sudo -i
# echo 1 > /sys/block/sde/device/queue_depth
# echo 1 > /sys/block/sdf/device/queue_depth
```

This command takes effect immediately however it's not persistent on rebooting so you'll eventually have to change the boot parameters.

References

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/145965/how-do-i-target-a-specific-driver-for-libata-kernel-parameter-modding
- http://marc.info/?t=130747326400001&r=1&w=2

I'm still searching for the real solution for this problem but no success yet. I hope this workaround works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the post - I'll play around with your suggestions and see if I have any success - would be great if that is the solution.

Comment: OK, first updates - first time I set the queue depth a zero fill failed after 639MB.... - Rebooted, checked the default queue depth which is 31 - changed it to 1 (as per your command), verified it is 1 and zero filled the drive again - now failed at 3.8GB.

Comment: And the second update: Zero filling the partition instead of the drive seems a bit more stable but still fails - after 6.9GB with a queue depth of 1. So look like the queue depth doesn't help :(

Comment: I'm running Linux on two PCs of Asus P7P55D-E EVO board, Ubuntu 14.04 and CentOS 7 respectively. In both PC, two HDDs attached to 88SE9123 ports and used for OS booting with btrfs RAID1 setup. Same 88SE9123 issue on both PC and same workaround worked on both. I tried various things such as [1] updated the HDD firmware [2] updated the mainboard bios expecting onboard 88SE9123 bios also updated [3] forced SATA link to 3Gbps instead of 6Gbps [4] disabled the VT-d on mainboard bios setting, with no luck. The only cure worked so far is to disable the NCQ. Very stable without NCQ.

Comment: You can see the hardware error messages with `dmesg` command. If you see the messages like the one in this page ([link](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=43160#c15)), then you're still using NCQ. So check what happened with your controller and HDD with `dmesg` command, and it would be helpful if you attach or include the problematic dmesg log in your question. I'm not an expert but hopefully someone knowledgeable may be able to help.

Comment: Updated the post with some logfiles (via Pastebin) - I'm not sure if I understand the dmesg output correctly, but it may be that the setting is indeed not respected...

Comment: In dmesg log of my computer, 88SE9123 controller is recognized as `AHCI 0001.0000 32 slots 2 ports 6 Gbps 0x3 impl SATA mode`. In your log, 88SE9128 is represented as `AHCI 0001.0200 32 slots 8 ports 6 Gbps 0xff impl SATA mode`. I mean **8 ports** looks strange. 9123 and 9128 is very similar controller, both provide 6Gbps 2 ports. One more thing, I see `ata14.00: ATAPI: MARVELL VIRTUALL, 1.09, max UDMA/66` in your dmesg log that I can't find in mine. Maybe you're running 88SE9128 in RAID mode? I'm not sure as mine doesn't support RAID mode. If so how about change it to AHCI mode?

Comment: If I were in your situation, I'd try to [1] update firmware ([link](http://sgcdn.startech.com/005329/media/sets/Marvell_88SE9128_Firmware/Firmware.zip)) [2] set controller to AHCI mode instead of RAID [3] downgrade the kernel to version lower than 3.15 (reason: bug on 3.15 or later? [link](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/40776#comment125182)). I'm using 3.13 in Ubuntu-14.04 and 3.10 in CentOS-7. Your kernel is 4.3, bleeding edge version. Maybe the easist way is to try live DVD of other distro to check if kernel version matters at all?

Comment: The firmware is up to date - I upgrade it to the latest available using a DOS based floppy disk - it is two ports. The weirdest part is that it says 9128 on the chip and 9123 in OpenSuSE. OpenSUSE Leap uses Kernel 4.x - I just checked, I'm not using the Kernel repo for OpenSUSE Leap, so I'm not on quite the latest. And lastly, I don't have any controls over the SATA card - my main BIOS is set to AHCI. The card's BIOS can be accessed when the Dell's is set to Legacy but offers no options whatsoever.

Comment: Ok, went ahead and tested OpenSUSE 13.2 with the older 3.16 Kernel as well as Windows where it works fine. - Just noticed you said earlier than 3.15... not sure where to find that offhand, might need to check tomorrow..

Comment: Just ran one dd with Ubuntu on kernel 3.13 (with ncq though) - error again.

Comment: With NCQ enabled on Ubuntu 14.04 with 3.13 Kernel, I experience many errors too on my machine just like you posted. You've done hard testing so far, however I think you need to check with NCQ disabled. I've never seen success case with NCQ enabled on 88SE91xx controllers in Linux environment.

Comment: To temporarily disable NCQ, you don't have to change boot parameter. Adjusting NCQ queue size to 1 by command like "echo 1 > /sys/block/sde/device/queue_depth" in root shell is enough. This command doesn't make records in syslog or dmesg, but it just works immediately. I checked this again in my system before I post this reply.

Comment: FYI, I uploaded dmesg log of my system ([link](http://pastebin.com/kYEM1UbR)). I booted without libata parameter for disabling NCQ, and ran command `btrfs scrub start /`. You can see many errors similar to yours in my log. After seeing these errors, I executed `echo 1 > /sys/block/sdg/device/queue_depth; echo 1 > /sys/block/sdh/device/queue_depth` command to reduce the NCQ queue size to 1 and ran the `brtfs scrub start /` command again. No errors this time.

Comment: Well, had a good nights sleep and used the Ubuntu LiveUSB again - setting ncq to 1 using the command line didn't change a thing for me - unfortunately, writing zeroes to the drive still failed. - And as you state, dmesg doesn't reflect the manual change...

Comment: You tried same kernel to my system and disabled NCQ. Now the only difference outstanding is that 88SE9123 on my system is in AHCI mode and 88SE9128 on your system seems to be running in RAID mode? In fact I'm not sure whether AHCI mode and RAID mode is correct term. Anyway, in your system you can clearly see your PEXSAT32 card being recognized as 8 ports device (though it has only 2 ports). Maybe you can ask Startech how to make your card recognized as normal 2 ports device. I hope you find a way to make your controller work in Linux. Good luck!

Comment: StarTech actually isn't sure what causes this either - it moved to escalated support and he suggested he would try as well - I have since queried the openSUSE Kernel mailing list too... - It seems like Marvell controllers have a history of problems... - but lets see what comes off this.